# Does $f^3$ integrable imply $f$ integrable?

Tags: integration

Let $f$ be a function defined on the close interval $[a,b]$. Does the riemann stieltjes integrability of $f^3$ imply the riemann stieltjes integrability of $f$ ? 
The answer is trivially no in the case of $f^2$, but I am not able to find a counterexample for the case $f^3$.

Comment: this may not be an "answer" but this should give you some idea....$\sum \frac{1}{n^3}$ is finite but $\frac{1}{n}$ is not finite.... SO?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik But here we integrate on a closed interval $[a,b]$, the trivial $\int_1^{\infty} 1/x^3 \mathrm{d}x$ won't work here.

Comment: @arbautjc : Valid point :D i missed that.... any how i will keep it as it is for time being until i think of a solution...

Comment: You put "Stieltjes" in your question.  Are you doing integrals like $\int_a^b f(x)^3 d\phi(x)$ or something?

Comment: Yes, I mean an integral w.r.t. a function: 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral

Answer (score 17):

You could try proving the following theorem : If $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann-integrable, and $\varphi : [c,d]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous where $f([a,b])\subset [c,d]$, then $\varphi\circ f$ is Riemann integrable.

You need to begin with the Riemann condition for integrability (difference between Upper and Lower sum is small), and use the uniform continuity of $\varphi$. It takes a little more work than that, but that is the essence of the argument.

Now just take $\varphi(x) :=x^{1/3}$, to see that your statement is true.

Comment: Wouldn't this argument be valid for $\varphi(x) :=x^{1/2}$ too? This is the trival counter-example from the OP.

Comment: No, because $x \mapsto x^2$ is not injective. However, given $f^3$, $f$ is uniquely determined.

Comment: No. Let $\varphi (x)=x^2$, $\psi (t)=\sqrt t$. Then $\psi \circ \varphi = |\cdot |\neq \text{Id}$.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt understand. My hypothesis is that $f^3$ is integrable and I have (if it is true) to show that $f$ is integrable, why should I start with the hypotesis that $f$ is integrable? This is exactly what I want to prove/confute.

Comment: You start with $f^3$ playing the role of $f$ in the above theorem, and $\varphi(x) =x^{1/3}$, so $f = \varphi\circ f^3$

Comment: I suppose that if we only consider $[a,b]$ such that $0\le a \le b$, then $\phi(x) = x^{1/2}$ would work?

Comment: @Prahlad Vaidyanathan, but for the map $\phi$ if some entry $x$ is negetive, then what about $\phi(x)$.