# Does the integrability of $ f^3 $ imply the integrability of $ f^2 $ and/or $ f $?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

We know that the integrability of $ f $ implies the integrability of $ f^2 $, but the integrability of $ f^2 $ does not imply the integrability of $ f $ (for example, the function $ f(x) = 1 $ when rational and $ -1 $ when irrational).

***Question***: However, does the integrability of $ f^3 $ imply anything about the integrability of $ f $? And what about higher powers?

Comment: I think it depends on the underline set. Do you consider $f$ as a function on a closed interval $[a,b]$ or on an infinite interval, say $[0,\infty)$ or $\mathbb{R}$? In the latter I can find a non-integrable function $f$ such that $f^3$ is integrable.

Comment: You can make implications but it depends on whether the domain Ω is bounded or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider $f$ on a closed interval [click here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611704/does-f3-integrable-imply-f-integrable?rq=1).

The statement does not hold for functions on infinite intervals, for example the function $f:[1,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is not integrable, but any power $f^n$ is integrable.

Answer (score 4):

That is false.
$$
   f =
\begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} &\quad 0 < x < 1\\
   0 \quad &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

is (Lebesgue)-integrable, but $f^2$ isn't.

This can be generalized to arbitrary greater than $1$ powers. We can say something more if either the domain or the functions are bounded.