# How any power $f^n$ is integrable?

Tags: real-analysis

I have  some  confusion in this  answer
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2920303/557708

My confusion  here  see the red  mark[image]

## My attempt :  $$f(x)= \frac{1}{x} ,  f^2 = f(f(x) = x , f^3 = f(f(f(x))) = f(x)= \frac{1}{x}$$

Here $f^3= f$ is  not integrable   but  in above  answer it said that any power $f^n$ is integrable im confusing  How  any power  $f^n$  is integrable ?

Comment: They are taking composition, they are raising $f$ to the $n$th power

Comment: I think you're misreading the notation.  I believe the exponent is intended to represent exponentiation, not repeated concatenation.  In other words, $f^2(x)= f(x) \times f(x)$, not $f(f(x))$.

Comment: @clark basically in my text book  $f^n$ written as composition

Comment: @jasmine Yes, but that notation isn't universal. Clearly for the author of the answer $f^2(x)=f(x)\times f(x)$. Note that he explicitly says "the $n$-th power".